# g++ -v says the program isn't currently installed but I know it is

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and when I run the command `g++ -v` I get

```
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install g++
```

So then I run `sudo apt install g++` and I get

```
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I think this problem has to do with my .bashrc file not telling my kernel about g++ but if that's the case then I don't know what to add to the file to make the kernel recognize the g++ command.

Also if I need to specify the location of the g++ folder in that file I don't know how to find it. `which g++` just returns empty, I'm guessing for the same reasons I'm having the original problem.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Likely the package is installed but you manually removed or broke the symbolic link between `/usr/bin/g++` and `/usr/bin/g++-5` - try `sudo apt install --reinstall g++`

Comment: `s/kernel/shell/g`

Answer (score 2):

As steeldriver suggested in their comment « Likely the package is installed but you manually removed or broke the symbolic link between `/usr/bin/g++` and `/usr/bin/g++-5` - try `sudo apt install --reinstall g++` »

The `sudo apt install --reinstall g++` did the trick.

---

<sub>Answer provided because there wasn't one</sub>

Comment: @Thomas there was no answer to accept, so Scabandari _correctly_ wrote one.